# How to unzip cats-vs-dogs data in kaggle?

Tags: python, kaggle

This is my first kaggle kernel and I am sure about things in kaggle.
I tried to create a new kernel for cats vs dogs classifier.

- I created a new kernel in https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/notebooks

Then,

```py
!ls ../input/dogs-vs-cats/
# sampleSubmission.csv  test1.zip  train.zip

!unzip ../input/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip
# this gives a report that looks like it works.
# it displays jpg files names
# but when I check the folder train, it does not exits

!ls ../input/dogs-vs-cats/train/
# there is no folder train


import os
print(os.listdir("../input/dogs-vs-cats"))
# ['train.zip', 'test1.zip', 'sampleSubmission.csv']
# there is no unzipped folder
```

How to access the data in kaggle kernel?

Comment: Have you made sure to try adding the destination to the unzip comand? Maybe it has something to do with what parts of the kernel is writeable by you. `!unzip ../input/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip . ` (note the added dot at the end)

Comment: you can also try: `os.system('unzip ../input/dogs-vs-cats/*.zip')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the unzipped files at the wrong place.

```py
Instead of: 
!unzip ../input/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip
!ls ../input/dogs-vs-cats/train/

Do this:
!unzip ../input/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip
!ls train/
```

To check in python

```py
import os
print(os.listdir("train"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the zip file into pandas,

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.zip')
df
```